# Get dynamically jquery populated textbox value onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

i am trying to get value of a textbox that i populate with an Onchang event using jquery. my code is as below:

```
     $('#cn-name').change(function(){

     var cnm = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'cnlist.php',
    data: { fun2: 'num', textc: cnm },
    success: function(snno){

        $('#cn-id').val(snno);
    }
    })


 });



 $('#cn-id').live("propertychange change click keyup input paste ",function(){

     var cnum = $('#cn-id').val();

     alert(cnum);



 });
```

Here, '#cn-name' is a selectbox and '#cn-id' is a text box (suppose to be hidden)

i get the value only when i click the textbox!

P.S i want that textbox to be hidden

Comment: `live()` is deprecated, use `.on()` with [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)!

Comment: So what's the issue? What's the question? It's not very clear from what you have in the question, we don't even know what textbox you want hidden as there's no markup...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting value with `.val()` is not supposed to trigger any event, but you can use [jQuery.triger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to manually trigger the event like this and then your event handler will be called

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'cnlist.php',
    data: { fun2: 'num', textc: cnm },
    success: function(snno){
        $('#cn-id').val(snno).trigger('change');
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! it worked like charm